# Java - Efficient (native?) version of PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1

Tags: java, sha1, hmacsha1

I am using PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 to hash passwords. (might sound weird, but thats not part of this discussion).

The issue: the implementation of java is damn slow. 2000 iterations take ~2 seconds on my machine. The native implementation of openssl needs for same input 0.05 seconds. While this is not the security i want (because c is so fast) it is way too slow (i can not go beyond 2000 rounds without pissing the users since hashing is done client side).

Can someone give me a suggestion or poke me at a library?

Comment: usually you want password hashing to be slowerish... or at least to take some time. But i doubt java is the problem here, modern java running on a modern JRE will be very fast, sometimes as fast as native code thanks to JIT, Hostpot, and other optimizations within the JRE. You may want to look into some of the good cryptographic libraries, such as BouncyCastle, etc.

Comment: You should show us your code. I measured the time it takes on my machine, without any warmup (so no JIT compilation yet), and it takes 24 millisesonds. I doubt my CPU is 100 times faster than yours.

Comment: my code is [here](https://gist.github.com/Kilobyte22/4aebab83110dea79b262)

Comment: Well, your code doesn't compile, and doesn't show how you measure the time it takes. And you should edit your question and post it here.